# What is the meaning of "as far as problems go"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is a paragraph from a book (Zero to One):

> But in February 2000, Elon and I were more scared about the rapidly
>   inflating tech bubble than we were about each other: a financial crash
>   would ruin us both before we could finish our fight. So in early March
>   we met on neutral ground—a café almost exactly equidistant to our
>   offices—and negotiated a 50-50 merger. De-escalating the rivalry
>   post-merger wasn’t easy, **but *as far as problems go*, it was a good one
>   to have.** As a unified team, we were able to ride out the dot-com crash
>   and then build a successful business.

I didn't understand the sentence written in bold. I know what is the meaning of its words and phrases, but I couldn't understand the meaning of the whole sentence.

Comment: as far as x goes=with respect to, as regards, in terms of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression meaning:

***[as far as something goes](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+far+as+goes)***:

> to the degree something is considered or exists
>
> - As far as gun control goes, I think we definitely need to make some changes. Their action is encouraging as far as it goes.

(Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms)

- Regarding the problems, that was a good one to have (compared to others possible worse problems).